# Length of sparse arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm having an array will take n values, but the values will be added to different index at different time. But, I need the length of the array at a particular time.

**Case 1**

```
var a = [1,2,3,3,4]

a.length //Returns 5 - OK
```

**Case 2**

```
var a =[]
a[20] = 2
a.length //Returns 21 but I would like it to return 1
```

How to get the length as `1` for the **case 2**?

Comment: The only way to get it to return 1 for the length is to only have 1 element in it... `a[0] = 2`  or are you saying you want `length` to return the number of elements with a value?

Comment: Why do you want to put the element on the 20th position? If not, you can use `push' to push elements in.

Comment: @PraneshRavi *''I'm doing it because it is possible''* this sounds WEIRD!

Comment: So when you say `a[20]=2` you're basically telling it to skip the first places and put my element in the given place. So the length should return the bigger number, isn't it so? If you still want to get an output 1 by using the custom position, maybe you can write a function to loop through the array?

Comment: @PraneshRavi Can you explain what you are trying to do?  If you simply want `.length` to return the number of defined values in the array then that's trivial, but it's not actually clear what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#compact) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2). You may try like this

```
var arrLen = _.compact(youArr).length;
```

If you want to use pure JS..you will need to write simple function. That will count number of elements not equal to false.

```
var len = 0;
arr.forEach(function(el){
  if (el) {count++;}
});
console.log(len);
```

As @vlaz mention [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) will also work.

For numbers I would use [Number.isInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) to get number count instead `typeof value !== "undefined"` as so on.

You can omit parseInt method, if you sure that values in array will always be integer type.

So in example below with parseInt = 4, without = 3

```js
var arr = [];

arr[7] = 1;
arr[17] = null
arr[33] = 0;
arr[66] = undefined;
arr[77] = '7';
arr[99] = -7;
arr[9001] = false;


var count = arr.reduce((x, v) => Number.isInteger(parseInt(v)) ? x+1 : x, 0);

console.log(count);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're awesome. I'm going with `lodash` instead of `underscore`. Thanks!

Comment: This will fail if the the value is falsey, e.g. 0, *false*, *undefined*, *null*, etc. A better test would be`arr.forEach((v, i) => len += arr.hasOwnProperty(i)? 1 : 0)` or `arr.reduce((a, v, i, arr)=> a+= arr..reduce((a, v, i, arr)=> a+= arr.hasOwnProperty(i)? 1 : 0, 0), 0)`.

Comment: @Vlaz Already mention it in his answer. But i will add his code too. So people have better understanding.

Answer (score 13):

A lot of the answers suggest either looping through the array or creating a new array and then counting that (what `_.compact` does). I think all of those are the wrong approaches since using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) makes this completely trivial.

```js
var arr = [];

arr[7] = 1;
arr[17] = 2
arr[33] = 0;
arr[9001] = 4

var count = arr.reduce(x => x+1, 0);

console.log(count);
```

It's one line or 19 bytes of code to do it. This is because `.reduce` will *not* go through empty spots in the array, so it will only visit explicitly populated indeces. Then just counts those.

Be aware that if you have any indeces explicitly set to `undefined`, they still count as populated as demonstrated. So if that's the case, then you will need to account for it in the callback, for example

```js
var arr = [];

arr[17] = 2
arr[42] = undefined

var count = arr.reduce(x => x+1, 0);
console.log(count);

var filteredCount = arr.reduce((x, value) => typeof value !== "undefined" ? x+1 : x, 0);
console.log(filteredCount);
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for the op or others: `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.map` actually have the same characteristic as `Array.prototype.reduce` that the callback function is not invoked for empty/unset elements.

Comment: Great solution, thank you. I add part of you're code into my answer. Feel free to comment for any issues.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to count the number of elements that are not undefined:

```js
var a = [];
a[20] = 2;

// count number of elements in a that are not undefined
var count = a.filter(x => typeof x !== 'undefined').length;

console.log(count); // prints 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count the 'keys' (i.e. populated indices) of the array:

```
Object.keys(arr).length
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the items with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

> **`forEach()`** executes the provided callback once for each element present in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays).

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4];

console.log(a.length); // 5
a[20] = 2;
console.log(a.length); // 21
var length = 0;
a.forEach(function () { length++; });
console.log(length); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will fit your needs although it's not clear why you would put an element to the 20th position.

```
function dynlength(array) {
    var length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] !== undefined) length++;
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first var a=[];
to a.length return length of elements in array

when you say a[20]='x';

the array actually get initialized with 21 elements (with 20th element set to your value) and remember 21 is the number of element in your array

if you want custom value try iterating in loop as

```
var count=0;
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
 if(a[i]!=undefined)
  {
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are two different values. Elements at indices 0-19 will be *undefined*, not null.

Comment: yea..edited my ans....just tried to put my solution...will ensure next time i make no mistakes..thanks for pointing out...! :D

Answer (score 0):

Using arr.length property will return the total length including the 'holes'

You can use forEach() method which skips the holes in the array.

```
var arr1 = [];
var count = 0;

arr1[20] = 2;

alert(arr1.length);// this will always return including 'holes'

arr1.forEach(function(ele, i) { //this will skip the holes and will take real values into account
   count++;
});
alert(count);
```

You can also check for 'undefined' values in each index and add to count variable. But be carefull in employing 'undefined' to empty 'holes' in array.

You can check http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch18.html#array_holes

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner solution could be to use [`Filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Just filter out the *truthy* values (include 0 though) and find the length. This will work even if a value is explicitly set to `undefined` or any other *falsy* value

```js
var a =[]
a[20] = 2;
a[10] = undefined;
a[15] = 0;
var x = (a.filter(i=> i===0||!!i )).length;
console.log(x)
```