# Can array.length be trusted?

Tags: javascript

```js
let arr = [];
arr[3] = undefined;
console.log('length: ',arr.length);

if(arr.length === 0){
  //I wanted to come here
}else{
  //But instead coming here
  console.log('>>',arr[0]);
  console.log('>>',arr[3]);
}
```

I've just noticed that if we're not using a `push` function to insert item into an array, the length will be updated, even if we assigning `undefined`. Clearly, the `arr` showing above is simply nothing inside.

During a conditional checking, how can we really sure that an array is empty? I can only think of manually looping thru the array and doing a `count++` which looks really redundant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of sparse arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787939/length-of-sparse-arrays)

Comment: `array.length` can always be trusted, as long as `array` is a Array, _not a Proxy_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Array.length:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

> The value is an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

When you *assign* `undefined` to an index of an array, that index becomes an existing property on said array. But, like any variable, it can have anything assigned to it, including `null` and `undefined`.

If you ever run into situations like this (which you shouldn't - sparse arrays are a terrible idea), you can check the `keys` or the `keys` and `values` of the array:

```js
const arr = [];
arr[3] = undefined;
console.log(Object.keys(arr)); // Not empty!

const allArrElmsAreUndefined = arr => Object.values(arr).every(item => item === undefined);
console.log(allArrElmsAreUndefined(arr));
```