# How to find an array length in JavaScript without "Empty Slot"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any built in method or properties or operator to find out an array length without any empty slots?

Comment: What's an empty slot per your requirement?

Comment: There is none, but you can check whether the index exists and filter those that do. For example: `[,,undefined,42].filter((_, i, arr) => i in arr).length // 2` or simply: `Object.keys([,,undefined,42]).length // 2`

Comment: Also relevant: [Length of sparse arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39787939)

Comment: How exactly do you define if "*array length*" if not by its `.length` property?

Comment: @Bergi I suppose they want to know the amount of filled slots.

Comment: @Adam  i was trying for "undefined" or elements inserted in higher indexes within an array. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @blex thanks that was really helpful. But I was thinking more of a method kind of approach like Object.values(array).length, is there any other methods like this one?

Comment: `var pokemons=Array(10); pokemons[1]=""; pokemons[2]="Pikachu"; pokemons[3]=null; pokemons[4]="Pidgey"; pokemons[5]=0; pokemons[6]=undefined; var x=pokemons.reduce((count,pokemon)=>count+=(!!pokemon),0);` x is equal to 2

Comment: Better yet: `count=0;array.forEach(()=>count++);console.log(count);`

Answer (score 2):

```
const arrayWithEmptyValues = [0, , , 1, , , , , 2, , , , 3]
const cleanArray = arrayWithEmptyValues.filter(function () { return true })
console.log(cleanArray.length)
```

Comment: You can clean this up further by replacing the filter callback function with an arrow function. `.filter(() => true)`

Comment: @3limin4t0r or eliminate the extra array altogether by using `.reduce` and counting one for each element. Then all you do is return a number, instead creating a new array to only return a number.

Comment: @Vladyslav Frizen Thanks a lot Vlad. But do you think there exists any other method like this Object.values(array).length?

Answer (score -2):

```js
console.log([1, null,"",,, undefined, '2',""].filter(obj=>obj!=="").length)
```

Comment: This will return `2`, but there are no empty slots so it should return `4`.

Comment: now it returns `4` but it needs to return `6` since there are still no empty slots, just 6 elements.

Comment: @pl2ern4 thank you for this filter method idea though, but in this case "" doesn't actually checks for undefined or null values. But I really appreciate it though. Happy coding :)